# How to code a component in design time that will only be created in runtime

Tags: dynamic, delphi-7

I recently asked how to create dynamic components that have a different name each time, I got extremely useful answers and my program has been running flawlessly

this is the basic idea of the code

```
 begin
  pnlTemp := TPanel.Create(Self);
  pnlTemp.Parent := Self;
  pnlTemp.Name := 'pnlDisplay' + IntToStr(iCountPanel);
  etc..

  iCountPanel := iCountPanel + 1;
end;
```

However I have encountered a new problem, I have searched on this forum as well as many other sources, but all I can find when I search is how to create dynamic components (which I know how to do). My problem is as follows:

When the panel (as seen above) is created in run time I want the user to be able to click on the panel and then a list of information regarding that specific panel will be displayed. I cannot just code this for pnlTemp as their will be many panels that have been created.

What I want to know is if there is a way to code the click event for "pnlDisplay[i]" even though this panel technically does not exist yet?

Comment: Maintain a dynamic collection of panels that you have created

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @David Heffernan, however I am fairly new to Delphi and so I ask if you could please elaborate on how to achieve what you suggest.

Comment: If you want to hold a single value, use a variable. But you have multiple values, number varying dynamically. So use a collection. For instance an array or a Dephi list.

Comment: Thank you very much, your advice is much appreciated. After your suggestion of arrays I researched a bit more on Delphi arrays as my knowledge was limited and I believe dynamic arrays will achieve the result I require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are properties like any other. Their handlers can be assigned at runtime. So simply assign an `OnClick` event handler to each Panel you create, and use the event's `Sender` parameter to know which Panel is being clicked.

```
constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  pnlTemp: TPanel;
  iCountPanel: Integer;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  iCountPanel := 0;
  ...
  while iCountPanel < ... do
  begin
    pnlTemp := TPanel.Create(Self);
    pnlTemp.Parent := Self;
    pnlTemp.Name := 'pnlDisplay' + IntToStr(iCountPanel);
    pnlTemp.Tag := iCountPanel;
    // other properties as needed...
    pnlTemp.OnClick := PanelClicked; // <-- ADD THIS
    Inc(iCountPanel);
  end;
  ...
end;

procedure TMyComponent.PanelClicked(Sender: TObject);
var
  Panel: TPanel;
begin
  Panel := TPanel(Sender);
  // use Panel as needed...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution @Remy Lebeau. I had to make some modifications to your idea, but I eventually got it working.